# Rails 3 App not creating production.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've just recently checked out a code, and everything seems fine, but after I decided to test the production environment via rails server -e production I notice there is no logs/production.log created, I thought it was some permission error so I deleted the development.log but it is able to recreate it but not with production.log

I'm on rails 3.2.13 by the way and I've tried updating all the way to rails 3.2.2 and my app is still unable to create a produciton.log

It does write a log if i touch log/production.log but it doesn't seem to be able to create a log from scratch.

Comment: Did you try `RAILS_ENV=production rails server`?

Comment: Yup just for testing purposes I did and still the same, though technically I already did rails server -e production

Comment: The log level in production is much less verbose than in development. Could it be that it hasn't hit an event that needs logging in production? Try changing the log level for production to `:info` in your config/environments/production.rb and run your app again.

Comment: Okay I finally got it, someone introduced this to the app on environments/production.rb

    config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)